# Swift Sort Two Dimensional Array

Tags: swift

I have declared the following variable:

```
var Results = [String : Int]()
```

Now i want to order this Array from small to Big, based on the Integer values.

I have tried this, but it is only working for the String values:

```
func getSmallestResult(fingerprintingResult:[String:Int]) {

    var closestObservationPoint:String = String()

    var myArr = Array(fingerprintingResult.keys)
    var sortedKeys: () = sort(&myArr) {
        var obj1 = fingerprintingResult[$0] // get ob associated w/ key 1
        var obj2 = fingerprintingResult[$1] // get ob associated w/ key 2
        return obj1 < obj2
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a 2 dimensional `array`, but a `Dictionary`. Try this:

```
let sortedDictionary = sorted(Results) { $0.0 < $1.0 }
println(sortedDictionary) // [(A, [1, 2]), (D, [5, 6]), (Z, [3, 4])]
```